# jsSHA, CryptoJS and OpenSSL libraries giving different results

Tags: javascript, cryptography, sha1, hmac

New to JS, I'm also learning to use crypto libraries.  I don't understand why signing/encoding the same message with the same secret yields differing results.

I'm using [jsSHA 1.3.1 found here](http://caligatio.github.com/jsSHA/), and [CryptoJS 3.0.2 described here](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) trying to create a base64 sha-1 encoded hmac signature.  Here's the code:

In html...

```
<script src="lib/jsSHA/src/sha1.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js"></script>
```

And in js...

```
var message = "shah me";
var secret = "hide me";
var crypto = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) + '=';

var shaObj = new jsSHA(message, "ASCII");
var jssha = shaObj.getHMAC(secret, "ASCII", "B64") + '=';

return  "crypto answer is " + crypto + " jssha answer is " + jssha;
```

Can you help me explain why these results differ?

> crypto answer is 3e929e69920fb7d423f816bfcd6654484f1f6d56= jssha
>   answer is PpKeaZIPt9Qj+Ba/zWZUSE8fbVY=

What's more, both of these differ with the signature I'm generating in rails, like this...

```
digest  = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1')
raw_signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, "hide me","shah me")
b64_signature = Base64.encode64(raw_signature).strip
```

(would have liked to supply a fiddle, which seems to be a very good common practice, but that, too, is new to me and I was unable to get one working for this question).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 errors in your code :)

You're missing the `enc-base64-min.js` for `crypto-js`. Without it, `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` will be `undefined`
You're missing a parameter when calling `.getHMAC()`. It's `.getHMAC(secret, secret_type, hash_type, output_encoding)`
With 1+2 adding a `=` isn't necessary (nor right)

```
<script src="lib/jsSHA/src/sha1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js"></script>  
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>  

var message = "shah me";
var secret = "hide me";
var crypto = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message, secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var shaObj = new jsSHA(message, "ASCII");
var jssha = shaObj.getHMAC(secret, "ASCII", "SHA-1", "B64");

return  "crypto answer is " + crypto + " jssha answer is " + jssha;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/29b6q/)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  That nearly works.  I see it works perfectly in the jsfiddle, but updating my code with your suggestions left me with two issues: 1) the jsSHA readme says to omit the algorithm name when including sha1.js.  Your suggestion on my localhost generated 'undefined format', choking on "SHA-1" as an output format (I think).  I band-aided this by including sha.js rather than sha1.js.  Good enough.  But tougher: (2) on my rig, crypto appended the trailing '=', but jsSHA did not.  The sigs are the same, though, so I am already grateful your great answer!

Comment: I just tried including the js from https://raw.github.../sha1.js as you did on jsfiddle.  Doing so now gives me a perfect result.  So thanks again.  My current project has the js copied locally after downloading the zip of 1.3.1.  I'm going to mark this correct (and +1).  Can you let me know what the correct practice is for including a lib like jssha?

Comment: A quick search didn't show a CDN which hosts this lib so I would go with a local copy.

Comment: Ah, but the local copy fails to add the trailing '='.  Should I just append one?  I'm a little confused about the best practice for including stuff (and about the semantics of the = in hmac).  I've opened a new question here and would be much obliged for more of your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672414/including-local-vs-remote-javascript-libraries

Comment: Why not just copy the current version from github and use this as I've done in the example?